# Loading properties from a file in a JBoss 6 Web Application

Tags: jboss, properties, jakarta-ee

Can I dump a **properties file** somewhere in one of the **JBoss 6** directories, and pick it up from the **classpath**?

Or even better, does anybody know the mechanism behind a configuration file like `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/jboss-logging.xml`?  Changes to this file seem to trigger an event, so that a running instance can process the modifications (without having to bounce the AS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is to configure `SystemPropertiesService` in `./conf/jboss-service.xml`.

This allows you to configure *system* properties in-place, or load them from a properties file:

```
<server>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService"
           name="jboss.util:type=Service,name=SystemProperties">

        <!-- Load properties from each of the given comma seperated URLs -->
        <attribute name="URLList">
            http://somehost/some-location.properties,
            ./conf/somelocal.properties
        </attribute>

        <!-- Set propertuies using the properties file style. -->
        <attribute name="Properties">
            property1=This is the value of my property
            property2=This is the value of my other property
        </attribute>

    </mbean>
</server>
```

For more details, refer to: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/admindevel326/html/ch10.html

Answer (score 1):

They have made this even easier in JBoss EAP 6 (AS 7).

1. Pass Property File as Startup Parameter

This can be added within the main start up script or passed as parameter

```
./standalone.sh  --properties=/Users/john.galt/dev/config/ds/jboss.properties
```

If these properties are read, they will be rendered in the server log as the first statement.

```
3:58:41,633 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Configured system properties:
        DSsettings.password = password
        DSsettings.user-name = admin
        DSsettings.connection-url = jdbc:oracle:fat:@activedb:1521:DEV
        [Standalone] =
        awt.nativeDoubleBuffering = true
```

NOTE: As these settings are logged in server log, ensure no clear text passwords are in the property files in production

2. Use passed in system properties
   You could use these system properties with following syntax.
   Example Usage in a data source file

   ```
   <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/ds" pool-name="cPool" jta="true" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
       <xa-datasource-property name="URL">

           ${DSsettings.connection_url}

       </xa-datasource-property>

       <driver>oracle</driver>
       ...
       <security>

           <user-name>${DSsettings.user-name}</user-name>

           <password>${DSsettings.password}</password>

       </security>
       ...

   </xa-datasource>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss 6 use: `./deploy/properties-service.xml`

Answer (score 0):

On JBoss AS7 properties-service.xml no longer exist, the below is the solution:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/how-to-inject-system-properties-into-jboss